# TYPO3: tx-form custom fluid templates and class for submit button

Tags: forms, configuration, yaml, typo3, typo3-12.x

I'm trying to **customize the form in TYPO3 V12**, formerly (up to V11) I just made my own partials and templates, but in V12 I cannot get that to work. (i get confused with the directory structure for the exact spot where to have the html available) ...

furthermore V12 introduced the possibility to **override the specific class value**, that is `form.renderingOptions.formNavigation.btnSubmitClassAttribute` only that I cannot get to work either ...

in a forum I found this worked out: [typo3forum.net](https://www.typo3forum.net/discussion/85556/eigene-yaml-konfiguration-fuer-formulare-wird-nicht-beachtet)
what is wrong with that snippet ?

I sometimes get confused also what cache to clear to be sure that I have the results of the latest code ... with yaml I have no idea at all ... (but this would be a separate question)